# SpringSecurity using JWT

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I am working on an application in Java, Spring, SpringBoot, Spring-Webflux. The application has a REST-interface where I want to autenticate the user using a provided JWT-token. Im not very good at security but I have managed to get it working using essentialy the following code-fragments.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<String> claimRoles; //from properties

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http, ReactiveAuthenticationManager am) {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authenticationManager(am)
                .securityContextRepository(tt(am))
                .authorizeExchange(e -> {
                    e.pathMatchers("/api/v3/protected/**").hasAuthority("MY_CLAIMS")
                            .pathMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                            .pathMatchers("/docs/**").permitAll()
                            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(
                                jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter())))
                .build();
    }


    private Converter<Jwt, ? extends Mono<? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>> getJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        final ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverter();
        final Converter<Jwt, Flux<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter =
                new ReactiveJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter(new CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(claimRoles));
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverterAdapter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    private final List<String> authoritiesClaimNames;

    public CustomJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(final List<String> authoritiesClaimNames) {
        this.authoritiesClaimNames = authoritiesClaimNames;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(final Jwt jwt) {
        return this.authoritiesClaimNames.stream().map(claimName -> {
            final var claims = jwt.getClaim(claimName);
            if (claims instanceof String) {
                return List.of((String) claims);
            } else if (claims instanceof ArrayList) {
                return ((ArrayList<String>) claims);
            } else {
                return Collections.<String>emptyList();
            }
        }).flatMap(Collection::stream).map(authority -> (GrantedAuthority) new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority)).toList();
    }
}
```

The application work but I want to be able to get hold of the user and especially the users JWT later in the business-code. What do I need to add to my code so I will be able to successfully get a SecurityContext from the SecurityContextHolder (currently its null)?

```
SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
```

The internet is filled with examples but Ive havent managed to adapt one to my needs.

Please, can anyone help me out?
BR

Comment: SecurityContextHolder doesn't work in WebFlux. Have you checked `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`?

Comment: But of course - that is the solution. I should have thought of that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

you can for instance get the token by just asking for it and it will magically get injected.

```java
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/token")
    public Token getToken(JwtAuthenticationToken jwtToken) {
        return new Token(
                     jwtToken.getToken(),
                     jwtToken.getAuthorities()
        );
    }    

    public record Token(Jwt token, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities){}
}
```

[here](https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1) is a full tutorial of setting up a spring server as an *resource server*

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I can do that or I can dig it out from the ServerWebExchange. This, however means I have to pass it around if I want to use it later in the code (I need it in a integration-request later on in the code). Im looking for a way to just grab it from a context where ever I need it - Im sure it should be possible.